# Is it possible to set an environment variable at runtime from Java?

Tags: java, environment-variables

Is it possible to set an environment variable at runtime from a Java
application?
In Java 1.5 java.lang.System class there is the getenv() method, I would
only need a setenv() method...

Is it possible to modify the environment variables in the java process itself; not in the child process.

Is it possible to achieve it through JNI? And how would that work?

Thanks.

EDIT:
Ok let me put it this way - Can we do the following with Java. Please answer.

1. Can we modify the environment of the current process?
2. Can we modify the environment of the parent process?
3. Can we modify the environment of the child process?

Hemal Pandya has answered that "You can modify the environment of current and child processes but not of the parent process that spawned this process." Do you agree with this ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve Vicky?

Comment: I suspect this question is very closely related to this previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529474/how-to-run-a-ksh-script-from-java-code

Comment: And this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/525212/how-to-run-unix-shell-script-from-java-code

Comment: @Vicky: The answers to your previous questions contain a lot of information that would be helpful in solving your problem. Perhaps you could explain what you have tried any why the solutions already given do not work for you.

Comment: @Vicky, have you finally found an answer to this problem?

Comment: I just found a possible need.  I am running an app that needs to load a native library.  It is dependent on other native libraries in the same directory it is in.  However java might not run in the same folder as the libraries and that folder is not in the "path".  So thinking that the native side of the DLL loader looks at the current process's path if I add the library folder to the PATH and then call "System.load("mylibrary"); it will find it's dependencies.

Answer (score 42):

**If my intuition is correct**, and you actually want to modify the environment for the benefit of a spawned (forked) sub-process (`Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`), then use [ProcessBuilder](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) instead of `exec()`.  You can build a custom environment via your `ProcessBuilder` instance's [environment()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#environment()) method.

If this is *not* what you are trying to achieve then kindly disregard this answer.

---

**UPDATE**

The answer to your three updated, specific questions is as follows:

1. Can we modify the environment of the current process?

   - **Not easily**.  Depends whether you want to change the process' environment, to change the value(s) returned by `System.getenv()` in the same JVM, or both.
   - As Greg Hewgill pointed out, to change the current process' environment you can call `setenv` or its platform-specific equivalent via JNI.  You may also employ the extremely convoluted method from *point 2* below, which works for any process (provided you have the permissions.)  However, be aware that in most JVMs this change might never be reflected in the values returned by `System.getenv()`, as the environment is more often than not cached at virtual machine startup in a `java.util.Map` (or equivalent.)
   - To change the JVM's cached copy of the environment, when a cache is used (see the source code in `System.java` in whichever JVM distribution you will be using to deploy), you may try hacking the implementation (via class loading order, [reflection](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/index.html), or [instrumentation](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html).)  In the case of SUN's v1.6 JVM, for example, the environment cache is managed by the undocumented `ProcessEnvironment` class (which you can patch.)
2. Can we modify the environment of the parent process?

   - **Extremely difficult, and highly non-portable**.  If you absolutely and imperatively have to, there are very specific hacks that you can employ:

     - Windows: [Dynamically Add/Edit Environment variables of Remote process](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/DynEnvVar.aspx)
     - *nix: [Is there a way to change another process’s environment variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205064/is-there-a-way-to-change-another-processs-environment-variables) -- this is a performance killer, as any process instrumented by `gdb` will be suspended for a non-zero amount of time.
3. Can we modify the environment of the child process?

   - **Yes**, through `ProcessBuilder` when spawning the process.
   - If the process has already been spawned when the environment alteration is required, you need *method 2* above (or some equally convoluted method, such as code-injection at spawn time, ulteriorly controlled through e.g. socket by the parent process.)

Note that all methods above, except for the one involving `ProcessBuilder`, are brittle, error prone, non-portable to various degrees, and prone to race conditions in multi-threaded environments.

Comment: I believe your intuition is correct, Vicky has been trying to solve this problem for weeks. See the related links in the question comments above.

Comment: Can you add 4. option of modifying environment of *running* child process? I assume it is same as 1.

Comment: @user482745 no; see option 3. second bullet.

Answer (score 15):

You can get a handle on the underlying map that `java.lang.ProcessEnvironment` is holding on to, and then put new stuff and remove stuff all you want.

This works on java 1.8.0_144. Can't guarantee it works on any other version of java, but it's probably similar if you really need to change the environment at run time.

```
private static Map<String,String> getModifiableEnvironment() throws Exception{
    Class pe = Class.forName("java.lang.ProcessEnvironment");
    Method getenv = pe.getDeclaredMethod("getenv");
    getenv.setAccessible(true);
    Object unmodifiableEnvironment = getenv.invoke(null);
    Class map = Class.forName("java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap");
    Field m = map.getDeclaredField("m");
    m.setAccessible(true);
    return (Map) m.get(unmodifiableEnvironment);
}
```

After you get the reference to the map, just add whatever you want and you can now retrieve it using the regular old `System.getenv("")` call.

I tried this its working in MAC not working in Windows in both os java version 1.8_161

Comment: Works with Java 7

Comment: works with java 8. Very useful for test scenarios

Answer (score 9):

@Snowbuilder's answer put me in the right track, however it was mysteriously not working with Oracle JDK 1.8.0_231 (he tested with minor version _144). Even though I was able to update the underlying Map (validated by printing out `System.getenv()` before and after adding a new property to the Map), the changes were not reflected when the new property was retrieved using `System.getenv("property")`.

After some investigation I found out that's because `System.getenv()` and `System.getenv("property")` end up using different static attributes of `java.lang.ProcessEnvironment`, which are initialized in the class' `static` block. So it doesn't matter if new properties are added to the Map retrieved using `System.getenv()`; these properties will not be available in the other Map used by `System.getenv("property")`.

So I changed the code from the other answer to deal with this scenario and came to the code below. Please note this will only work if you retrieve properties using `System.getenv("property")`; if you use `System.getenv().get("property")` then his answer is what you need. The usage is as follows:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private static Map<String, String> getModifiableEnvironment() throws Exception
{
    Class<?> pe = Class.forName("java.lang.ProcessEnvironment");
    Method getenv = pe.getDeclaredMethod("getenv", String.class);
    getenv.setAccessible(true);
    Field props = pe.getDeclaredField("theCaseInsensitiveEnvironment");
    props.setAccessible(true);
    return (Map<String, String>) props.get(null);
}
```

This method should be used as follows:

```
getModifiableEnvironment().put("propName", "propValue");
System.getenv("propName"); // this will return "propValue"
```

Comment: this worked for me in jdk11 as well. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks it worked even on windows. It should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 7):

In response to your updated question:

1. Can we modify the environment of the current process?
   **Yes**, if you use JNI to call `setenv()` or something. You probably don't need to do this though, and it may not work in all situations.
2. Can we modify the environment of the parent process?
   **No**.
3. Can we modify the environment of the child process?
   **Yes**, using `ProcessBuilder`.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think so, at least not purely in Java, but why do you need to do this?  In Java it's preferable to use properties via `System.getProperties()`, which you can modify.

If you really must, I'm sure you could wrap the C `setenv` function in a JNI call - in fact, I wouldn't be surprised if someone has done so already.  I don't know the details of the code, though.

Comment: I would like to do that, because a unit test needs a class that ultimately uses an environment variable. But some refactorring and another mock is probably going to be the way.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the environment of current and child processes but not of the parent process that spawned this process.