# How can I set an environment variable in a cross-platform way?

Tags: haskell, cross-platform, environment-variables

I can easily read an environment variable using `System.Environment.getEnv`. However, `System.Environment` does not have any corresponding `setEnv` function (as far as I could tell).

How do I set an environment variable from a Haskell program? I would prefer a cross-platform solution. (So just executing `export VAR=val` or using `System.Posix.Env` is not quite what I'm looking for.)

Comment: Note that base 4.7.0 now has a `setEnv`.

Comment: @EmmanuelTouzery: Awesome. Could you put that as an answer for increased visibility? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that base 4.7.0 now has a `setEnv` in `System.Environment`. So for the present or near future it's sorted out.

However if you need this feature in versions <4.7.0 (which is my case currently), I have also extracted from [the commit that adds the feature](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/attachment/ticket/7427/0001-Add-setEnv-unsetEnv-to-System.Environment.patch) the functions needed to make this work with an older base version.

However I seriously lost patience on this one and did it rather ugly but it works for me...

The mess is that there are 3 functions to call in a windows environment: `putenv`, `SetEnvironmentVariableA` (ASCII) and `SetEnvironmentVariableW` (widechar, utf16). The patch that was committed to base 4.7 does this automatically, but I did something more ugly by lack of time (I may yet it clean it up).

Here's what I have:

```
setEnv_ :: String -> String -> IO () 
setEnv_ key value = withCString key $ \k -> withCString value $ \v -> do 
  success <- c_SetEnvironmentVariable k v 
  unless success (throwGetLastError "setEnv") 

putEnv :: String -> IO ()
putEnv v = void (withCString v $ \vv -> c_putenv vv)

foreign import stdcall unsafe "windows.h SetEnvironmentVariableA" 
  c_SetEnvironmentVariable :: CString -> CString -> IO Bool 

-- SetEnv_ :: String -> String -> IO () 
-- SetEnv_ key value = withCWString key $ \k -> withCWString value $ \v -> do 
--   success <- c_SetEnvironmentVariable k v 
--   unless success (throwGetLastError "setEnv") 
--  
-- Foreign import stdcall unsafe "windows.h SetEnvironmentVariableW" 
--   c_SetEnvironmentVariable :: LPTSTR -> LPTSTR -> IO Bool 

foreign import ccall unsafe "putenv" c_putenv :: CString -> IO CInt
```

Obviously use `CPP` to put the whole thing in a `#ifdef` for windows only. As you can see I have the code for the widechar call, but I commented it currently. I think for my use-case it would probably be enough to just call `putenv` but well it works as it is. So here's how I call it then:

```
setEnv_ "LANG" localeStr
putEnv $ "LANG=" ++ localeStr
```

My problem is that I'm primarily a linux user at home and I don't like doing too much work on windows at home, and I put *a lot* of energy to get this and other things to work properly on windows, and I can't bring myself to clean this up further. But with this code and the original patch you should get this to work on base <4.7 without much problems.

Answer (score 3):

On POSIX platforms you can use `System.Posix.Env`, which has a `putEnv` function. That's more portable than running `export`, although unfortunately not truly cross-platform.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I actually saw that module after posting the question, but I would really like something that would work on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

A hint that this is not possible cross platform is that the Java API does not have a `putenv`.
See also this [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580085/is-it-possible-to-set-an-environment-variable-at-runtime-from-java).

The solution for the most frequent use case is to pass an appropriately constructed environment when `exec`-ing programs.