# set permanent environment variables using java

Tags: java, linux, bash, environment-variables, permanent

I have a java application which runs on a linux machine many times at a single login. At the beginning of it, I need to set some environment variables for further use. I did that by appending my variables and their values at the end of both `~/.bashrc` and `~/.profile` files.
In order to make those variables permanent, I should call "`source ~/.bashrc`" or "`source ~/.profile`". The problem here is that the source command can not be called through java because of it's scope concerns.

**In a single word:** How can I set permanent environment variables on my linux machine at the begining of my java application?

Comment: Instead of `java ./myprog`, how about `MYVAR=1 java ./myprog`? Also see [Set Linux environment variable programmatically in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14022487/608639).

Comment: @jww I need to do it inside java, the value of variables calculated at the beginning of my java code

Comment: *"the value of variables calculated at the beginning of my java code..."* - Then it sounds like you should use the cited dup. Vamsi Mohan Jayanti answer looks like the one you should use. Ryan Stewart's answer also has some useful information.

Comment: @jww what is that? keep in mind that I will use those environment variables later in other bash scripts