# Eclipse jUnit : Cannot use environment variables across unit tests

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, intellij-idea, junit

I need to use some environment variables in my unit tests. Consider the following test class

```
public class MyTest 
{

private String myVar=null;

@Before
    public void setUp()
    {
        myVar = System.getEnv("myEnv");
    }

@After
    public void tearDown() {}

@Test
    public void myTestMethod()
    {
        assertNotNull(myVar);
    }
}
```

now in the eclispe debug/run settings of the `MyTest` class, i define the environment variable as

`myEnv=myVal`

and when I run the `MyTest` class as a `jUnit` test, the `myTestMethod` passes.

However, when i try to run `myTestMethod` as a `jUnit` test, it gives me a `NullPointerException`.

The only way to make it pass is to create a **new** run/debug configuration specifically for `myTestMethod` and creating the environment variable again in the new configuration.

This is extremely frustrating as I can have dozens of environment variables and tests.

Is there any way to solve this problem in eclipse? I have not worked with intelliJ but does that also suffer from the same problem? Or is it more of a jUnit issue?

Comment: What's your OS? Where do you set the environment variable?

Comment: i am on mac osx. i set the environment variable in eclipse run configuration of the class

Answer (score 0):

Existing launch configuration are not reused when running a single test method: see [Eclipse bug 213316](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=213316), except in the JUnit view. Perhaps there are plug-ins that implement the behavior you want. Alternatively, you could implement the behavior you want yourself, based on the [Eclipse source code](http://git.eclipse.org/c/jdt/eclipse.jdt.ui.git/tree/org.eclipse.jdt.junit/).

No solution, but a shortening: Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and click on the run button or on a run configuration menu item to open the previous launched or the corresponding launch configuration.

You may also take into consideration to change your code to solve the problem of [at runtime unchangeable environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/580097/6505250):

- In production code use `Env.getenv(...)` instead of `System.getenv(...)`:

  ```
  public class Env {
      private static Function connector = System::getenv;
      public static void setConnector(Function newConnector) {
          connector = newConnector;
      }
      public static String getenv(String name) {
          return connector.apply(name);
      }
  }
  ```
- In test code set environment variables by redirect `Env.getenv(...)`:

  ```
  @Before
  public void setUp() {
      Map env = new HashMap<>();
      env.put("myEnv", "42");
      Env.setConnector(env::get);
      //...
  }
  ```