# Gradle export environment returned from script

Tags: gradle, environment-variables, exec, gradle-task

I am trying to write gradle task which do the following:

1. Executes script to obtain some data (let's say there is curl inside)
2. Sets a environment variable with this data.

I would like to set this env variable so other gradle tasks can use it for further processing.

My code looks like this:

```
task myTask(type: Exec) {
    executable "sh"
    args "-c", "export", "myVar=\$(sh ./script.sh)"
    doLast {
       println System.getenv("myVar") 
    }
}
```

However when executing I see in the console all my env variables being printed (export KEY=VALUE) and System.getenv("myVar") prints null.

What am I doing wrong? Maybe there is better way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1):

Dynamically updating/settings environment variables is something easily done or possible based on the answers in these questions (many more):

- [Is it possible to set an environment variable at runtime from Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580085/is-it-possible-to-set-an-environment-variable-at-runtime-from-java)
- [How do I set environment variables from Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318239/how-do-i-set-environment-variables-from-java)

I think a better solution is to write to temporary file of the data you need, then read it as part of your Gradle task:

```
task myTask(type: Exec) {
    executable "sh"
    args "sh ./script.sh"
    doLast {
       new File("my-file.data")
    }
}
```